# Can't fill in 2D array with value in while loop

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, sorting

I'm trying to sort some values out and put them into a 2D array but I keep getting that all the places in the array has value 0.

My code looks a little like this, this is the short version. The important bit is the "kategori" array and what I want to do is to fill the array at each specific place ex [0,a] with the value of y.

```
class Program
{
    struct Säljare
    {            
        public int artiklar;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Säljare[] s = new Säljare[6];

        for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
        {                          
            Console.Write("Antal sålda artiklar: ");
            s[x].artiklar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s.Length);

        int[,] kategori = new int[2,6];

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        int y = 0;
        while (y < s.Length)
        {
            if (s[y].artiklar < 50)
            {
                kategori[0, a] = y;
                a++;
            }

            else if (50 <= s[y].artiklar)
            {
                kategori[1, b] = y;
                b++;
            }          

            y++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Antal");

        int z = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < a; x++)
        {
            kategori[0, x] = z;
            Console.WriteLine(s[z].artiklar);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < b; x++)
        {
            kategori[1, x] = z;
            Console.WriteLine(s[z].artiklar);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged? an integer array will always be full of zeroes when initialized.. What does `s.Length` equate to? You would have to include what `s` is and what data it contains for us to really help you here.

Comment: Yeah I've tried but there are no errors that turn up. s.Legnth is referring to a struct that is a part of the code, it equals to 6 in any case.

Comment: There may be no `errors` that turn up. But at least you could follow your logic and monitor your variables to give you a clue where you are going wrong here.. This doesn't seem like it would be hard at all to track down with minimal debugging.

Comment: The thing is I've tried using traces, writing out what the int b and int a and so forth equals to and the else if has worked so far without problems. Its just the actual array that for some reason doesn't get any values.

Comment: I just ran your code and it is working as coded. Both [0,x] and [1, x] arrays get their values populated. Can you show an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean (I'm very new to programming excuse my ignorance). My input will be 6 different numbers that will go to s[]. The output that I want is the number inside the _kategori_ array after the while loop.

Comment: Have a look at SO's [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). With a working MCV that reproduces your problem, we can more easily see what might be the problem

Comment: Thank you for the information, I've edited the code now. Hopefully it gives a better picture of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your edit:
The problem lies with you never modifying z. It always remains at 0 (which results in you filling your kategori array with 0 only). Check the following code. If your intention is to print kategori, use my edit.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        struct Säljare
        {
            public int artiklar;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Säljare[] s = new Säljare[6];

            for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
            {
                Console.Write("Antal sålda artiklar: ");
                s[x].artiklar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine(s.Length);

            int[,] kategori = new int[2, 6];

            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;

            int y = 0;
            while (y < s.Length)
            {
                if (s[y].artiklar < 50)
                {
                    kategori[0, a] = y;
                    a++;
                }

                else if (50 <= s[y].artiklar)
                {
                    kategori[1, b] = y;
                    b++;
                }

                y++;
            }

            //Use this to print kategori
            for (a = 0; a < 2; a++)
            {
                for (b = 0; b < 6; b++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", kategori[a, b]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Antal");

            int z = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < a; x++)
            {
                kategori[0, x] = z; //z is always 0
                Console.WriteLine(s[z].artiklar);
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < b; x++)
            {
                kategori[1, x] = z; //z is always 0
                Console.WriteLine(s[z].artiklar);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure it is the mismatched fields though. I've edited code in my question maybe it is easier to see now.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Your intention is still not clear to me. But I've written the answer assuming you are trying to print kategori.